# Can the MATLAB editor show the file from which text is displayed?

Tags: matlab, text, display

Using a certain library, one function was using another one which was calling `size` without semicolon. This lead to "text noise" in my main script.

Obviously with breakpoints is easy to isolate the line in which the text is printed, but I'm curious about if there is a way to know which function has printed some text in the command window.

Please notice that I'm not asking about adding the filename to my own display use, but to any call of this function during the execution.

Comment: One way would be to go to the function and check the orange warning markers on the right of the editor, but that's almost as laborious as using breakpoints.

Comment: well, I think the other way is to use `echo functionName on` and `echo functionName off` to turn on and off specific functions, and decide which function you want  to view the print outs and which ones you don't and then go into the functions and fix the issue (or leave it, simply add `echo function on/off` in front of your code before execution.

Comment: To @Adriaan's point, there's a built-in [code analyzer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/check-code-for-errors-and-warnings.html) that will [display a report for all warnings in the file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/matlab-code-analyzer-report.html).